# Ionic Deploy Cannot Find ZIP

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Ionic Deploy has been working perfectly up until this week. It will find an update but it does not apply it. I recently setup deploy manually following the Pro documentation and these are the errors I get on an Android emulator.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): /data/user/0/app.identifier/files/www.zip (No such file or directory)
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): error in opening zip file
```

If anyone can help I will be extremely grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: The problem lies within the webview plugin. I upgraded cordova-plugin-ionic to the latest version then set the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to version 1.1.19 until the Ionic team makes a fix.